# window.close(); in laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to close the browser in laravel controller when I clicked the logout.I want to write  java script  `window.close();` in controller(laravel 5.3).

```
 public function logout(){
    //Session::flush();
    Auth::logout();
    //return Redirect::route('close');
}
```

I created my page using master and child page structure.(ie) displayed child page in home page using yield('content') in sampleApp.blade.php(master page)

Answer (score 1):

Latest browser versions do not allow any script to close a window that was not initially opened by the same script. This is a security precaution and you cannot do anything about that.

You can check [`Window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) documentation page to read more about it.

I suggest you follow the best practice, which is redirecting the user to home page after they log out.

(and of course you cannot close the browser from your controller)

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right. I forgot about this feature in my answer. Thanks for the useful information.